# Filter (searching) on Microsoft Azure (graph) API

Tags: azure, filter, azure-ad-graph-api

I would like to query the Microsoft Azure AD by passing either a mobile number or a postal code. I am able to filter using the `givenName` using the `startsWith()` function but not able to search with mobile/postal code.

My request is `users?$filter=postalCode%20eq%20'560036'&api-version=1.6`

and getting the response:

```
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en",
      "value": "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'postalCode' of resource 'User'."
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried that in Graph Explorer too, seems to be unsupported :\

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I was trying this on an Azure AD **B2C** tenant. This is not supported on this type of tenant.
I've missed the note in the docs about this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http

The note's text is below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to this old [post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2014/02/10/support-for-disjunctiveor-filter-clauses-in-the-graph-directory-service/) in Microsoft Developer you can add OR clause to filter more than one field if you use startsWith() function.

`users?$filter=startswith(postalCode, '560036') OR startswith(mobileNumber, '123456')`

Of course, you still have to encode equal sign, parenthesis and spaces